# Laravel 8 - using AuthCheck middleware and just trying to check Has Username in session but it gives an error Error Description is below

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-middleware

using AuthCheck middleware and just trying to check Has Username in session but it gives an error Error Description is below

> Error
> ErrorException
> Attempt to read property "headers" on string LoginController
> C:\xampp\htdocs\larave8auth\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php:191

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    function login()
    {
        return view('login.login');
    }
    function checkLogin(request $request)
    {
        $validate=$request->validate([
            'email'=>'required|email',
            'password'=>'required|min:5|max:15'
        ]);
        
        $user=User::where('email','=',$request->email)->first();
        if(!$user)
        {
            return back()->with('fail','we  don\'t recognised your email');
        }
        else
        {
            
            if(Hash::check($request->password,$user->password))
            {
                Session::put('username',$request->email);
                return redirect('/dashboard');
            }
            else
            {
                return back()->with('fail','Password don\'t match');
            }
        }
    
    }

    function dashboard()
    {
        return view('login.dashboard');
    }
}
?>
```

**AuthCheck.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthCheck
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
         if($request->session()->has('username'))
         {
            return "true";
         }
         else
         {
            return "false";
         }
         
    }
}
?>
```

**web.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\LoginController;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/


Route::get('/login',[LoginController::class,'login']);
Route::post('/checkLogin',[LoginController::class,'checkLogin'])->name('checkLogin');
Route::group(['middleware'=>['AuthCheck']],function(){
    Route::get('/user', [UserController::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('/dashboard',[LoginController::class,'dashboard']);
});
?>
```

Comment: Which of these files is `VerifyCsrfToken.php` and which is line 191?

Comment: Did you assign the middleware a key in your application's app/Http/Kernel.php file? [Assigning Middleware To Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes). Also `return "true"` and `return "false"` will return strings, not sure if that works. Use `true` and `false` (without quotes)

Comment: Did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Because your middleware is just returning a string, not a redirect. You do return `$next($request);` or `return abort(404);` when you want to allow system to continue processing the request ahead. Your middleware must return a `Response` object, or `$next($request)` :

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (session()->has('username')) {
        return $next($request);
    } else {
        return abort(404);
    }
}
```

Comment: Telling the OP Why they need to do this will make this into an answer

Comment: @sta i am new bie and i want to check wether session value comes or not how do i check?

Comment: @peteranderson you can check with helper as `if(session()->has('user'))`

Comment: $sta i need to print or echo or return value true or false or whatever it returns and if possible i need to print session value too. Thanks for interest and reply

Comment: @peter you can set the true false value with set a session. as like `session(['user_status' => true]);`